# Is there any way to get user's motherland name using facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there anyway to get user's motherland name using graph API?

I've tried to get user's name, but Facebook returns English name although user's motherland is not English zone.

I want to get user's motherland language name.

somebody help me!!

Comment: This is called "Language-specific name" (http://www.facebook.com/help/405674989468892/) in Facebook, but as I know it's not accessible via `Facebook Graph API`

Answer (score -1):

Try accessing the `name_format` field of the User object, this is equivalent to the `name_format` field in the [User FQL table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) and is documented as:
*The user's name formatted to correctly handle Chinese, Japanese, Korean ordering*

For me (English language) it appears the same as the `name` field, but should be different for other locales

Example call is:
`https://graph.facebook.com/<USER ID>?fields=name_format&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`